# Kendo UI browser support for Dataviz

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

Kendo UI docs state that Dataviz is supported on IE7+ (see http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/dataviz/supported-browsers). However, I was not able to run the examples on IE7 (actually IE11 running in IE7 mode), e.g. this one: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/area-charts/index. It appears that the visualization widgets use SVG which is not supported on IE7. So is the Kendo UI documentation wrong about supported browsers? What is even more surprizing is that the same example runs fine in IE8 mode - I don't know how, because IE8 does not support SVG either!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Kendo UI switches to VML for IE7/8. So all features work on those browsers. Also, there is some issue with running IE7/8 under emulation mode. On real IE7/IE8 the demos work fine.